# Compare 2 or more column values in arbitrary order

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need a quick way to compare 2 or more values from different tables where the orders are arbitrarily stored in sql server.  The data comes from a 3rd party who will not change.

Example data below shows the same item described in two ways.  the remaining columns contain other data that i am joining.

```
table1
i    j   other columns...
1    2   ...


table2
i    j   other columns
2    1   ...
1    2   ...
```

right now for 2, i do a union query to cover both directions (i=i, j=j / i=j, j=i) .  but if you expand to 3, that is 9 possible orders.

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table1.i = Table2.i AND Table1.j = Table2.j

UNION

SELECT * FROM Table1 INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table1.i = Table2.j AND Table1.j = Table2.i
```

is there a way to order data returned from the first two columns before doing the comparison so i don't have to create all the unions?

Comment: As posted this doesn't make any sense. It is probably pretty clear to you but all we have is an extremely vague description of something. Can you provide some actual details about your problem.?

Comment: I'm not sure I'm understanding your question.  What are your expected results?  And perhaps what are your expected results with additional sample data?

Comment: It seems like you're trying to compare EVERY column from table 1 against EVERY column from table 2.  You can programatically do this by accessing INFORMATION_SCHEMA and dynamically building your SQL statement based off of that.  You cannot actually change the order of the columns before comparing but you should never need to.  The physical order of the columns is, for this case, meaningless, unless your column names are also meaningless but that indicates a much larger problem.

Comment: The database design seems not to be good, but you say you must live with it. So your best bet may be to write a database function accepting as many fields as needed, sorting them and putting out the sorted list as a string, e.g. concsorted(i, j, k, l) returning something like '1,2,50,200'. Then you would join using this: `from t1 join t2 on concsorted(t1.i, t1.j, t1.k, t1.l) = concsorted(t2.i, t2.j, t2.k, t2.l)`. Good luck.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner That sounds like what I need. next question is how is that on performance compared to union queries.  Ill have to run some tests

Comment: @ThorstenKettner my tests and many sources high recommend not to use functions in the where clause

Comment: Okay, so SQL Server has problems with functions in SQL. I didn't know that. So either you write an ON clause with all permatuations or you do what Nathan Skerl suggests in his answer: store the function result in the table, then it's just comparing two columns that you can even index. (You can even make this a unique index so as to prevent duplicates.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit: New xml approach**

I wonder how this approach performs:

```
select  *, cast(    '<c>' + cast(i as varchar) + '</c>' +
                    '<c>' + cast(j as varchar) + '</c>' +
                    '<c>' + cast(k as varchar) + '</c>'
            as xml).query('for $a in /c order by $a return concat($a, "/")').value('.', 'varchar(100)')
from    @Table1 o
```

This can be wrapped in a function and referenced in a persisted column... which should scale very well for you:

```
create table dbo.Table1 (pk int identity(1,1) primary key, i int, j int, k int);
insert into dbo.Table1
    values(1, 2, 3), (3, 1, 2), (4, 5, 6), (9,9,9);
go

create function dbo.fn_GenerateCompare(@i int, @j int, @k int)
returns varchar(100)
with schemabinding
as
begin
return 
(
    select cast('<c>' + cast(@i as varchar) + '</c>' + 
                '<c>' + cast(@j as varchar) + '</c>' +
                '<c>' + cast(@k as varchar) + '</c>'
    as xml).query('for $a in /c order by $a return concat($a, "/")').value('.', 'varchar(100)')
);
end

alter table dbo.Table1
    add Compare as dbo.fn_GenerateCompare(i, j, k) persisted;


select * from dbo.Table1
```

Returns:

```
pk  i   j   k   Compare
--  -   -   -   -------
1   1   2   3   1/2/3
2   3   1   2   1/2/3
3   4   5   6   4/5/6
4   9   9   9   9/9/9
```

Your query should now be really simple. Slap an index on the new `Compare` column and it should fly.

---

**Original Post:**

I like the *sorted list* idea proposed by Thorsten.  Heres a rough idea of how it might be done.  Performance would be greatly improved by persisting this `compare` column on the table (trigger or persisted computed column?)

```
declare @Table1 table (pk int identity(1,1) primary key, i int, j int, k int)
declare @Table2 table (pk int identity(1,1) primary key, i int, j int, k int)

insert into @Table1
values(1, 2, 3), (3, 1, 2), (4, 5, 6), (9,9,9)


insert into @Table2
values (2, 1, 3), (6, 4, 5)


--since the order is unimportant, concatenate the columns into a sorted array
--note how 1,2,3 and 3,1,2 both result in the same compare value:
select  *
from    @Table1 o
cross
apply   (   select  cast(value as varchar) + '/'
            from    @Table1
            unpivot (value for c in (i,j,k)) as u
            where   pk = o.pk
            order 
            by      value
            for xml path('')
        )d(compare)

--now, bring in the 2nd table
select  [src] = 1, pk, compare
from    @Table1 o
cross
apply   (   select  cast(value as varchar) + '/'
            from    @Table1
            unpivot (value for c in (i,j,k)) as u
            where   pk = o.pk
            order 
            by      value
            for xml path('')
        )d(compare)
union all
select  [src] = 2, pk, compare
from    @Table2 o
cross
apply   (   select  cast(value as varchar) + '/'
            from    @Table2
            unpivot (value for c in (i,j,k)) as u
            where   pk = o.pk
            order 
            by      value
            for xml path('')
        )d(compare)


--now just group them to find the matching rows
select min(src), min(pk), compare
from    (   
            select  [src] = 1, pk, compare
            from    @Table1 o
            cross
            apply   (   select  cast(value as varchar) + '/'
                        from    @Table1
                        unpivot (value for c in (i,j,k)) as u
                        where   pk = o.pk
                        order 
                        by      value
                        for xml path('')
                    )d(compare)
            union all
            select  [src] = 2, pk, compare
            from    @Table2 o
            cross
            apply   (   select  cast(value as varchar) + '/'
                        from    @Table2
                        unpivot (value for c in (i,j,k)) as u
                        where   pk = o.pk
                        order 
                        by      value
                        for xml path('')
                    )d(compare)
        )grouped
group
by      compare
having  count(*) > 1;
```

Comment: Why would you not just to a join with the first and second table using the unpivot query you show first?

Comment: just being verbose to help explain whats happening. you could collapse them into a single query.

Comment: Last note.  this method works, but takes 10 times longer to run than just using a union query.  All other options took even longer except john's, but that didnt work if both tables are in an arbitrary sort order.

Comment: just to note, my selection of this as the answer was based on the original post

Comment: @blindguy do let us know if you try the 2nd approach. In my limited testing it was ridiculously faster to persist the compare